# Вывод данных из консоли c++

Tags: c++, qt, консоль, bat, виджет

У меня есть bat файл который выполняет загрузку файлов. Я хотел вывести все данные которые он даёт в отдельное окно в программе (например, graphicsView или textArea). Сделал что-то:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    QString program = "myfile.bat";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
    while (myProcess){
        ui ->label->setText(myProcess->read());
    }
    delete ui;
}
```

Но последняя строка не считывает данные. Как сделать считывание всех данных из консоли (их может быть разное количество) и выводить их в текстовый элемент в программе? И ещё мне нужно чтобы не появлялось окно cmd (сейчас это так и есть)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь сигналом `readyReadStandardOutput`:

```
connect(myProcess, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [&]() {
    ui->label->setText( myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() );
});
```

Консоль отключается в pro-файле:

```
CONFIG -= console
```